# why filter is not working in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to filter my list using `input` field and `date field` on button click .When I filled this field "to station "DEL" and "from station" "PNQ" "flight_date" "10-01-2017" .it should should one result .current it show no result .

here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/k4FBxqufETslgYxm4zEx?p=preview

```
$scope.searchClick =function(){
  if($scope.fromStation!='' && $scope.toStation!='' && $scope.departDate !=''){
    $scope.names = $scope.names.filter(function(item){
      return item.to_station === $scope.toStation 
      && item.from_station === $scope.fromStation
      &&  item.flight_date === $scope.departDate
    })
  }
```

expected output

```
{
    "to_station_name": "Delhi",
    "to_station": "DEL",
    "from_station": "PNQ",
    "from_station_name": "Pune",
    "depart_time": "12:00AM",
    "arrival_time": "4:00PM",
    "PNR": "AL_201",
    "flight_date": "10-01-2017",
    "fare": "900"
  },
```

Comment: Please edit the relevant code from the link into this post. The link will eventually expire, at which point your post will have little value for other users with similar problem. Additionally, by linking the code rather than posting it here, you are essentially asking people who are trying to help you to jump through unneeded hoops to provide that help.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your input type from date to text to get it working.

EDIT : since you want to keep date input, try this :

```
//Initialize departDate as a js date object
$scope.departDate = new Date();
//Function to convert js date object to string 
function formattedDate(d = new Date) {
  let month = String(d.getMonth() + 1);
  let day = String(d.getDate());
  const year = String(d.getFullYear());

  if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
  if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

  return `${day}-${month}-${year}`;
}
$scope.searchClick =function(){
  if($scope.fromStation!='' && $scope.toStation!='' && $scope.departDate !=''){
    console.log($scope.departDate)
    console.log(formattedDate($scope.departDate))
    //Use formattedDate function to compare your departDate with your model data
    $scope.names = $scope.names.filter(function(item){
      console.log(item.flight_date)
      return item.to_station === $scope.toStation 
      && item.from_station === $scope.fromStation
      &&  item.flight_date === formattedDate($scope.departDate)
    })
  }
}
});
```

Comment: By the way, you might want to use two lists : one containing full data, the other one containing result. Otherwise you will truncate your data when you use the filter.

Comment: it is not correct how user select date..please remove this anwser

Comment: Updated my answer to keep date input type. But be careful, this type does not work on every browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparisons of the dates aren't equal. You need to convert both strings into a valid Date object before you can compare them.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var defaultNames = [{
      "to_station_name": "Delhi",
      "to_station": "DEL",
      "from_station": "PNQ",
      "from_station_name": "Pune",
      "depart_time": "12:00AM",
      "arrival_time": "4:00PM",
      "PNR": "AL_201",
      "flight_date": "10-01-2017",
      "fare": "900"
    },
    {
      "to_station_name": "Delhi",
      "to_station": "DEL",
      "from_station": "PNQ",
      "from_station_name": "Pune",
      "depart_time": "8:00AM",
      "arrival_time": "11:00AM",
      "PNR": "AL_203",
      "flight_date": "06-01-2017",
      "fare": "800"
    },
    {
      "to_station_name": "Delhi",
      "to_station": "DEL",
      "from_station": "PNQ",
      "from_station_name": "Pune",
      "depart_time": "11:00AM",
      "arrival_time": "2:00PM",
      "PNR": "AL_204",
      "flight_date": "09-01-2017",
      "fare": "800"
    },
    {
      "to_station_name": "Pune",
      "to_station": "PNQ",
      "from_station": "DEL",
      "from_station_name": "Delhi",
      "depart_time": "10:00AM",
      "arrival_time": "1:00PM",
      "PNR": "AL_202",
      "flight_date": "11-01-2017",
      "fare": "900"
    },
    {
      "to_station_name": "Pune",
      "to_station": "PNQ",
      "from_station": "DEL",
      "from_station_name": "Delhi",
      "depart_time": "8:00AM",
      "arrival_time": "10:00AM",
      "PNR": "AL_208",
      "flight_date": "14-01-2017",
      "fare": "1000"
    },
    {
      "to_station_name": "Pune",
      "to_station": "PNQ",
      "from_station": "DEL",
      "from_station_name": "Delhi",
      "depart_time": "10:00AM",
      "arrival_time": "2:00PM",
      "PNR": "AL_211",
      "flight_date": "13-01-2017",
      "fare": "1000"
    }
  ];

  function getNames() {
    if ($scope.fromStation != '' && $scope.toStation != '' && $scope.departDate != '') {
      let departDate = new Date($scope.departDate);
      departDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
      $scope.names = defaultNames.filter(function(item) {
        let dateArr = item.flight_date.split("-");
        dateArr = dateArr.reverse();
        let dateFormat = dateArr.join("-");
        let flightDate = new Date(dateFormat);
        flightDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        return item.to_station === $scope.toStation &&
          item.from_station === $scope.fromStation &&
          departDate.getTime() == flightDate.getTime();
      })
    } else {
      $scope.names = defaultNames;
    }
  }
  $scope.fromStation = '';
  $scope.toStation = '';
  $scope.departDate = '';
  $scope.names = [];
  getNames();

  $scope.searchClick = function() {
    getNames();
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  From:: <input type="text" ng-model="fromStation" placeholder="From station"> TO:: <input type="text" ng-model="toStation" placeholder="To station">
  <br></br>
  DEPART Date:: <input type="date" ng-model="departDate" placeholder="select date">
  <button ng-click="searchClick()">search</button>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in names">
      FROM: {{ x.from_station_name }} ------ TO:{{ x.to_station_name }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```