# why $filter not showing filter data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to filter my list using $filter .My input paramater

```
"TO" : "DEL"
"FROM" :"PNQ"
"DEPART Date" : "10-01-2017"
```

it should show one output .this one

```
{
    "to_station_name": "Delhi",
    "to_station": "DEL",
    "from_station": "PNQ",
    "from_station_name": "Pune",
    "depart_time": "12:00AM",
    "arrival_time": "4:00PM",
    "PNR": "AL_201",
    "flight_date": "10-01-2017",
    "fare": "900"
  },
```

here is my code
https://plnkr.co/edit/k4FBxqufETslgYxm4zEx?p=preview

currently it is not showing anything when I click `search` button

```
$scope.searchClick =function(){
  if($scope.fromStation!='' && $scope.toStation!='' && $scope.departDate !=''){

     $scope.names = $filter('filter')($scope.defaultNames, function(item){
        var time1 = moment(item.flight_date, "DD-MM-YYYY");
       var time2 = moment($scope.departDate, "DD-MM-YYYY");
       return item.from_station_name ===  $scope.fromStation &&
       item.to_station_name === $scope.toStation && 
       time1.valueOf() == time2.valueOf()

     });

  }


}
```

Comment: You already had working answers here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633805/why-filter-is-not-working-in-angular-js/44634085#44634085

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your `$scope.searchClick()`:

```
$scope.searchClick = function() {
  if ($scope.fromStation !== '' && $scope.toStation !== '' && $scope.departDate !== '') {
    $scope.names = $filter('filter')($scope.defaultNames, function(item) {
      var time1 = moment(item.flight_date, "DD-MM-YYYY");
      var time2 = moment($scope.departDate, "DD-MM-YYYY");
      var times = time1.valueOf() == time2.valueOf();
      $scope.fromStation = item.from_station_name;
      $scope.toStation = item.to_station_name;
      return $scope.fromStation, $scope.toStation, times;
    });
  }
};
```

It was an issue with your `return`statement.

[**plnkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/bxJxy266bziNCybTai6z?p=preview)

Comment: could you please explain your answer ?$scope.fromStation = item.from_station_name;
      $scope.toStation = item.to_station_name;
      return $scope.fromStation, $scope.toStation, times;

Comment: it is working fine but i didn't get why you assign values and why you set return value comma seprated

Comment: In your return statement, you are comparing values not delegating them. I did this instead. By comma separating it runs a series of expressions, in order, and then returns the result of the last of them. With `&&` you're saying "return a if a is falsy, return b if a is truthy".

Answer (score 0):

Please check the updated plunker. The equals condition is wrong. I have modified return statement as below

```
if(item.from_station ===  $scope.fromStation &&
       item.to_station === $scope.toStation && time1.valueOf() == time2.valueOf() ){
         return item
       }
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/lIh1pGs2tmp3hWhTPMcX?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Change your SearchClick function as below

```
    $scope.searchClick =function(){
  if($scope.fromStation!='' && $scope.toStation!='' && $scope.departDate !=''){

     $scope.names = $filter('filter')($scope.defaultNames, function(item){
        var time1 = moment(item.flight_date, "DD-MM-YYYY");
       var time2 = moment($scope.departDate, "DD-MM-YYYY");
       return item.from_station ===  $scope.fromStation &&
       item.to_station === $scope.toStation && 
       time1.valueOf() === time2.valueOf()

     });

  }


}
```

And input you are giving is wrong , $scope.departDate is in MM/DD/YYYY format , change your input to
"TO" : "DEL"
"FROM" :"PNQ"
"DEPART Date" : "01-10-2017" //10th Jan 2017